# How can I package my perl script as a 32-bit executable?

Tags: windows, perl, executable, windows-7-x64

I'm on **64-bit Windows 7** machine, and I've been using `PAR:Packager` to package my scripts as `.exe`'s.

However, I now need to run these `.exe`'s on a **32-bit Windows 7** machine.

Is there anyway to package it as a 32-bit executable from a 64-bit machine? (is it possible with `PAR:Packager`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install a 32-bit perl on your 64-bit machine, but most folks will recommend you just keep a 32-bit VM laying about for those times you need to publish software for legacy machines.